# location.origin notable to test for null when file: protocol

Tags: javascript

Anyone see what is wrong with the following code, this is run on a URL with file:/// protocol:

```
var origin = location.origin;
if (origin) {
    console.log("origin NOT null");
} else {
    console.log("origin is null");
    origin = "";
}
console.log(origin);  // returns null
console.log(typeof origin);  // returns string
```

I'm baffled, it seems I am getting hold of a string called 'null' rather than a proper null value?

Comment: Yeah, `console.log(origin)` therefore returns `"null"` not `null`.  So.... for what reason are you accessing `location.origin`?

Comment: Seems location.origin is just a bit flaky, ended up using
origin = location.protocol + "//" + location.host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/origin-0.html#origin):

> If scheme is "file", then the user agent may return a UA-specific value.

Chrome returns `"file://"`

Firefox returns `"null"`

The only thing wrong with your code, is that it seems to not meet your needs, unfortunately you don't say what your needs are.

If you're interested in whether the <del>protocol</del> (scheme) is `file:`, use `location.protocol`.

(The first part of a URL is called the *scheme*, because 'file' is not a protocol).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

location.origin returns string instead of null, thats you get the first if statement running instead of the second one. what i think you should do is to get the host name instead . which is `location.hostname` which returns null for file:/// ---
[location hostname](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hostname.asp)